# Change APK File Version Automatically in Android

Tags: java, android, apk

I have  a `.APK` file. with some release version X. Now i want to change the `.APK` File Version name and Version code automatically without changing Attributes values in Manifest file.

I know with this code we can get the current version code and version name and we can change it in our application code. But  how can we set permenently the altered values in our Manifest file

```
PackageManager package_manager=this.getPackageManager();
String package_name = package_manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
int version_code=package_manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

Now we can change this thing in code like that

```
package_manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName="1.5.2";
```

and

```
package_manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode="2"
```

But this not worked for me when i finished my activity and open `Manifest` file. I will found the same  version name and version code as exist at the start of application. Above code Implementation not throwing any exception, But why its not change the `Manifest` attribute values ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: version name and version code **are** written in the manifest. you cannot change it without changing the manifest. nothing is supposed to change those once the package has been signed, as it would void the signature. and you don't have the signature on the phone, do you ?